# checking if a nested column exists in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

lets we have following following

```
case class SubRecord(x: Int)
case class ArrayElement(foo: String, bar: Int, vals: Array[Double])
case class Record(
  an_array: Array[Int], a_map: Map[String, String], 
  a_struct: SubRecord, an_array_of_structs: Array[ArrayElement])

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Record(Array(1, 2, 3), Map("foo" -> "bar"), SubRecord(1),
         Array(
           ArrayElement("foo", 1, Array(1.0, 2.0, 2.0)),
           ArrayElement("bar", 2, Array(3.0, 4.0, 5.0)))),
  Record(Array(4, 5, 6), Map("foz" -> "baz"), SubRecord(2),
         Array(ArrayElement("foz", 3, Array(5.0, 6.0)), 
               ArrayElement("baz", 4, Array(7.0, 8.0))))
)).toDF
```

[image: Output]

[image: Output for valid path]
[image: Output for invalid path]

Here we get value if a column(path) exists, other wise we get an exception,
But i want to get value like 'NOT_FOUND' in this case, is it possible???

> Expected output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found a better solution, we can just *safeCol()* in place of *col()* method

```
 def DataFrameSafeCol(df:DataFrame)(path: String): Column = {
      Try(df(path)) match {
        case Success(x) => x
        case Failure(_) => lit("NOT_FOUND")
      }
  }
```

> Then we can use as below

```
val safeCol=DataFrameSafeCol(df)(_) // function currying
df.select(safeCol("column_name")).show
```

Answer (score -1):

The Way I have done it, like below

> Please share If anyone has a better solution ??

I have implemented following methods

```
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

def getValue(df: DataFrame, path: String)= {
    when(lit(Try(df(path)).isSuccess),
      Try(df(path)) match {
        case Success(_) => df(path)
        case Failure(_) => lit("")
      })
      .otherwise("NOT_FOUND").as(path)
  }
```

- getValue() -> checks for path in dataframe and gives values as required

> OUTPUT

[image]